# recognizing template file names in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

When looking at a typical view in Django, there's usually an icon in the margin beside the template filename passed to `render`.  You can also click on the string and hit "Ctrl+B" to jump to the template.

I have my own methods that I pass a string defining which template to use and it'd be nice if I could have PyCharm recognize that and allow me to quickly jump to the file.  Is there a way to get PyCharm to recognize that method argument as being a template filename?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Django is enabled in your project,

Also, you can right-click folder containing the templates, and selected ‘Mark-as’ which in the last 5 as far as I remember and select ‘Template Folder’

Comment: I've done these and this allows recognition of template filenames in calls to `render`, but it doesn't work on functions you define yourself (hence my issue).  Somewhere PyCharm has defined known methods in Django as accepting template filenames, but I can't find where that is or if it's possible to edit that.

Comment: That will never work as the IDE will never check that the string is equal to a template name

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.  The IDE _does_ check the string when you call `render` because something somewhere is telling it to.  I want to also have it check the string in the methods I define by telling the IDE to do that but I don't know how.